# How to change the link of a file in a sub-directory to be accessible from the root director?

Tags: php, .htaccess, file, path

I'm currently coding an Admin Panel, and for the sake of organization, I've made it so that all of the pages are located in a sub-directory instead of the root directory and I want to access these pages in the sub-directory from the root link. For example, the index.php is in the root directory and is accessible from:

```
http://localhost/index.php
```

But the rest of the pages are located in a sub-directory like so:

```
//What the current link is
http://localhost/pages/page.php

//What I want the link to be
http://localhost/page.php
```

Some of my pages are in sub-directories of the sub-directory like so:

```
//What the current link is
http://localhost/pages/page1/page.php

//What I want the link to be
http://localhost/page1/page.php
```

As you can see, I simply want to eliminate the primary sub-directory from the link, which is `pages`.

I've looked around on the internet and from what I can tell, this is achievable through `.htacess` but I couldn't find anything that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly won't find a perfect solution you can simply copy and paste to solve all your tasks. That expectation is a strange on. Instead you are expected to actually understand how the tools you want to use work and to be able to find your own solution. For that there really are enough good examples here on SO and in addition there is an __excellent_ documentation of apache's rewriting module available with just two mouse clicks.

Anyway, her is a suggestion, you still may have to tweak it to your situation:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /pages/$1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you so much! This did exactly what I needed it to do.

Comment: Sure. Then it is a wise move now to really understand that snippet. So that you can solve the next task yourself. As said: there is an _excellent_ documentation available. It comes with really good examples and is very precise. _Did_ you take a look into it now?